# How do concat an array in PostgreSQL with data like this?

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to concatenate the `denominations` for all objects items same `id`:

```json
[
  { id:1, details: { denominations : [ { code: "USD",value :100} ] } },
  { id:1, details: { denominations : [ { code: "USD",value :110} ] } },
  { id:2, details: { denominations : [ { code: "USD",value :100} ] } },
  { id:2, details: { denominations : [ { code: "USD",value :110} ] } }
]
```

To

```json
[
  { id:1, details: { denominations : [ { code: "USD", value: 100 }, { code: "USD",value :110} ] } },
  { id:2, details: { denominations : [ { code: "USD", value: 100 }, { code: "USD",value :110} ] } }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, but if your json document has more parts that you are not showing, then you will need a different approach:

```
with invars as (
  select '[
    { "id":1, "details": { "denominations" : [ { "code": "USD","value" :100} ] } },
    { "id":1, "details": { "denominations" : [ { "code": "USD","value" :110} ] } },
    { "id":2, "details": { "denominations" : [ { "code": "USD","value" :100} ] } },
    { "id":2, "details": { "denominations" : [ { "code": "USD","value" :110} ] } }
  ]'::jsonb as j
)
select jsonb_build_object(
         'id', e->>'id', 
         'details', jsonb_build_object(
                      'denominations', jsonb_agg(d.*)
                    )
       ) as result
  from invars i
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(j) as e(top)
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(e.top->'details'->'denominations') as d(detail)
 group by e->>'id';
```

working [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sm1cz9XC)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer depends on exact details.

To aggregate the first (only?) array element from "denominations" across the whole input, a single unnest will do:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_build_object('id', j.val -> 'id'
                        , 'details', jsonb_agg(j.val #> '{details,denominations,0}'))
FROM   tbl t, jsonb_array_elements(t.js) j(val)
GROUP  BY j.val -> 'id'
ORDER  BY j.val -> 'id';  -- optional
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nClbz6Xj)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the PostgreSQL JSON's aggregation functions. For example, if you have a table named 'your_table' and a JSONB column called 'data'. The code will look like this then:

```
SELECT
  id,
  jsonb_build_object('denominations', jsonb_agg(value)) AS details
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    jsonb_array_elements(details->'denominations')->>'value' AS value
  FROM your_table
) AS subquery
GROUP BY id;
```